# Average of Vectors squared minus the square of the averaged vectors

Tags: vectors, average, means

I have already asked this question in Physics, but as someone pointed out it is more appropriate to place it here.

Say I've obtained a series of 3D vectors, (**x**, **y**, **z**), with a different vector at different points in time. I want to obtain the second moment of this set of vector's fluctuations in time. This is given by:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2$,

where **M** is the vector in 3D, and the average is over time. To me, you can solve this simply by taking:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2 = <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** )  $ \cdot $ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $> - <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $> \cdot <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $>$.

However, I have seen this solved by decomposing the vector along different Cartesian axis:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2 = < $ **M** $_x^2 > - < $ **M** $_x >^2 + < $ **M** $_y^2 > - < $ **M** $_y >^2 + < $ **M** $_z^2 > - < $ **M** $_z >^2 $.

This is shown on page 2548 in Pitera *et al.*, *Biophysical Journal*, 2001, **20**, 2546–2555. [Paper Link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349501762261).

I just wanted some clarification if this second method is correct, and I guess whether the first is also. To me, the second method is not possible as you cannot decompose $<$ **M** $>$ as they have. Less so if you then square the decomposed parts.

Thank you for any help, and apologies for any grievances about the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of the square is the average of the square of the components by linearity of expectations:
$$
\langle\mathbf M^2\rangle=\langle M_x^2+M_y^2+M_z^2\rangle=\langle M_x^2\rangle+\langle M_y^2\rangle+\langle M_z^2\rangle
$$

The square of the average can be decomposed into components, and no cross terms will survive, since we're evaluating an inner product in an **orthonormal** basis. (In a non-orthonormal bases, this decomposition would not be valid.)
$$
\langle\mathbf M\rangle^2=\langle M_x\hat x+M_y\hat y+M_z\hat z\rangle^2=\left(\langle M_x\rangle \hat x+\langle M_y\rangle \hat y+\langle M_z\rangle \hat z\right)^2=\langle M_x\rangle^2+\langle M_y\rangle^2+\langle M_z\rangle^2
$$
Does this clear up the logic behind the decomposition?

Comment: Ahh, makes sense now. Thank you for clearing that up. I'm afraid I can't upvote as I do not have 15 reputation but I appreciate the help anyway :)